# How to set entity for planet's name - dialogflow

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am making a chatbot to ask basic questions about solar system.
My main concern is how to set the entities for training phrases.
example:

1. What is the mass of moon?
2. Moon's mass
3. Tell me the mass of moon?

I have added an image below.
My main concern is how to set the entites for `mass` and `body`. I have made a custom entity for mass as `@body_mass` and not sure how to do for planets/objects name. So that I can receive these values in backend. It is not recognizing in Diagnostic Info

[image for what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocBkW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be by creating a `@Property` entity which can detect "What" a user would like to know about a planet, for instance:

- Height
- Mass
- Age
- Average pet per alien living on the planet
- etc..

Then you create another set of entities called `@Planet` with which you detect "Which" planet your user wants to know something about, for instance:

- Earth
- Mars
- Saturn
- etc..

Then you could create one intent called "Get Planet Info intent" and put example phrases such as:

- What is the `@Property` of `@Planet`
- How `@Property` is `@Planet`

By doing this you save yourself a lot of time because you don't have to create phrases for "What is the height of Earth" and "What is the height of Mars". You just capture a sentence for the property and the planet entity and it should work for every combination in your entities.

You could even improve upon this by adding [synonyms](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-options#map) for the entities such as:

- Height: Tall, Long
- Age: Old, young
- Mass: Big

In your code all the information you have to check for is which `@Property` and which `@Planet` did Dialogflow detect, so it saves you from having to check for things such as Mass_Planet_A, Mass_Planet_B like you would now.

Comment: Well, I implemented that. One more thing I want to ask -> My intent is `UserAsks` and Entities are `@body-mass` and `@space-object`. Now I want to add more functionality like' what is radius of space object ?' Then Do I have to include this type of question in `UserAsks` intent or make a new one?

Comment: The general rule for this would be that an intent represents a collection of phrases for a goal your user is trying to complete. In this case that would be ask to get information about a planet, anything related to that AND use those entities should work in the same intent. Space object is a bit vague so its difficult to say, if it is something like a planet id add it to your current intent, if you expect questions like, "What is the size of space" (Clearly not a planet) I'd make a new intent for it.

Comment: I will try... .